# Get Control under cursor

Tags: c++, qml

I`m try to get control under cursor. At my example i can get only red rectangle, but i need get other also.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Item {
        id: parentPanel
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onMouseXChanged: moveMouse()
            onMouseYChanged: moveMouse()
            function moveMouse()
            {
                currentControl.text = parentPanel.childAt(mouseX, mouseY).color ? parentPanel.childAt(mouseX, mouseY).color : "not colored"
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: redRect
               anchors {
                fill: parent
                leftMargin: 50
                bottomMargin: 50
            }
            color: "red"
            Rectangle {
                id: yellowRect
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                    leftMargin: 50
                    bottomMargin: 50
                }
                color: "yellow"
                Rectangle {
                    id: greenRect
                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                        leftMargin: 50
                        bottomMargin: 50
                    }
                    color: "green"
                }
            }
        }

        Text {
            id: currentControl
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

I have screenshot from running program. Green rect inside yellow, yellow inside red. I need get control ref when mouse cursor over control.

[image: Success get red color]

Comment: as @Nick Cano already noticed, you have to loop through all the children in the mouse scope to find a topest item (or maybe with biggest `z`). use `Item.children` and `Item.mapToItem`. Also, pay attention, in current state the `Text` item also the children of `parentPanel`. I advice you to use the same `objectName` for these items you want to search through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with QML, so I don't know the exact syntax for this, but it seems like you want to loop until you find the inner-most control and get the color of that. Here's some C++ish pseudo-code

```
auto control = parentPanel.childAt(mouseX, mouseY);
while (control)
{
    currentControl.text = control.color ? control.color : "not colored";
    control = control.childAt(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Of course, this code assumes that the X and Y passed are absolute, not relative. If the are relative, you would need to decrement them by the location of `control` in each consecutive loop.